# Lock Child TR to Parent TR in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a table in Javascript and I can't use my expand row function after using a tablesorter plugin. I can only expand the hidden TRs before using the tablesorter.

I looked it up and it appears I would have to lock the hidden TR child with my parent TR>

My table code is as follows:

```
$('<tr>').html("<td class='IndicatedDispatch'></td>" + "<td>" + $(this).find("TripID").text() + "</td><td>"
       + $(this).find("RouteNum").text() + "</td><td>"
       + monthArray[theMonth] + " " + $(this).find("ArriveDate").text().substr(8,8).replace("T"," ") + "</td><td>"
       + monthArray[theMonth] + $(this).find("DepartDate").text().substr(8, 8).replace("T", " ") + "</td><td>"
       + $(this).find("CommodityHandle").text() + "</td>").addClass($(this).find("IsDispatched").text() === "0" ? "DispatchNo" : "DispatchYes").appendTo('#dallas');

        $('<tr>').html("<td colspan='6'><p>" + $(this).find("DeliverySequence").text() + "</p></td>").hide().appendTo('#dallas');
    });

    $("#dallas").tablesorter();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("tr").click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            var $target = $(event.target);
            $target.parent().next().slideToggle();
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Basically, how can I expand using my setTimeout function after sorting my table?

Much appreciated.

Tried this and it does not expand at all now:

```
 $('<tr>').html("<td class='IndicatedDispatch'></td>" + "<td>" + $(this).find("TripID").text() + "</td><td>"
       + $(this).find("RouteNum").text() + "</td><td>"
       + monthArray[theMonth] + " " + $(this).find("ArriveDate").text().substr(8,8).replace("T"," ") + "</td><td>"
       + monthArray[theMonth] + $(this).find("DepartDate").text().substr(8, 8).replace("T", " ") + "</td><td>"
       + $(this).find("CommodityHandle").text() + "</td>").addClass($(this).find("IsDispatched").text() === "0" ? "DispatchNo" : "DispatchYes").appendTo('#dallas');

        $('<tr data-associatedId="hiddenTr1">').html("<td colspan='6'><p>" + $(this).find("DeliverySequence").text() + "</p></td>").hide().appendTo('#dallas');
    });

    $("#dallas").tablesorter();

    setTimeout(function () {
 $("tr").click(function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     var $target = $(event.target);
     $('#' + $target.attr('data-associatedId')).slideToggle();
 });
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *lock* ?

Comment: as in append the hidden TR that starts with DeliverySequence to the top part portion of TRs so I can expand my TR with hidden TR after using tablesorter()

Comment: need to use event delegation, plugin will replace the dom within table when sorted and your event binding will be lost